# WCF basicHttpBinding with Transport security specifying message credential type

Tags: wcf, security, basichttpbinding, transport

I've been given a wsdl for a service which VS2010 generated the following binding as part of it's configuration.

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NotificationHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

I'm a little confused as what the message node will do given the mode is set to Transport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. This will not be used at all. It is safe to remove it.